# Why am I locked at 20 settlers?

Tags: fallout-4, mods

I am looking to use the "Sim Settlements" mod for Fallout 4, but I can't seem to get past 20 settlers. Is the settlement limit fixed based on any factors? I understand Charisma is a part of the equation and that it's 10 + your Charisma modifier, but I'm looking to make a metropolis, I can't be running around adventuring in gear that looks like I came out of a thrift store.

The ideal situation is to have 40 settlers where I can have a large metropolis of generated houses.

Is the settlement limit 20 people and **without vanilla charisma gear are there any ways to remove it**?

Comment: In the Sim Settlements options do you have it using your charisma to calculate the max settlers?

Comment: @Xantec Yes, the settings are for maximum settlers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Sim Settler mod, but in unmodded Fallout 4, your settler limit (including companions) is ten plus your charisma stat, including bonuses from clothing and, while fast travelling, temporary bonuses from consumables.

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Charisma#Maximizing_Charisma) charisma can reach values as high as 48.